# Difference between Method.otherMethod and otherMethod?

Tags: java, list, class, linked-list

The below is an excerpt from a file in a project creating Huffman Trees. When the 
"public class HLinkedList" is initialized by itself, the separate file (also shown below) of HTreeNode 's methods such as .next, .left, .right have no problem working in HLinkedList's file. Once the "extends java.util.Abstract~" is put in place, the HTreeNode methods cannot be referenced, and I resorted to copy-pasting HTreeNode into the same file, which is why the first lines of code show it as such. The thing with having both of these in the same file is that it's causing collision(I think) between HLinkedList.HTreeNode and HTreeNode, as I kept the HTreeNode file just in case. This happens in a separate file Huffman_coder which originally used both HLinkedList and HTreeNode files very well (or at least without compile level error) until I decided to extend java.util.Abstract~

```
public class HLinkedList<HTreeNode> extends java.util.AbstractSequentialList<HTreeNode>
{

public class HTreeNode {


    public HTreeNode left;
    public HTreeNode right;
    public HTreeNode next;
    public int frequency;
    public char value;
    public String code;
    public HTreeNode(int freq, char val, HTreeNode l, HTreeNode r, HTreeNode n, String code) // code is the path taken to this node, how to explain it in code?
    {
        value = val;
        frequency = freq;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        next = n;
        code = ""; // just initialized ,but have to think through logic.
    }
}

 HTreeNode head;
static int nItem;

public HLinkedList() //constructor
{
    head = null; //inital value
    nItem = 0;//counter

}


public void insertIntoPosition(HTreeNode node, int position) //inserts into position
{
    //first, the case where it's already in the list.
        HTreeNode currNode = head;
        while(currNode.next != null)
        {
            if(currNode.value == node.value)
            {
                currNode.frequency++;
            }

            currNode = currNode.next;           
        }
        if(currNode.value == node.value)
        {
            currNode.frequency++;
        }
```

HTreeNode file:

```
public class HTreeNode {


    public static  HTreeNode left;
    public HTreeNode right;
    public HTreeNode next;
    public int frequency;
    public char value;
    public String code;
    public HTreeNode(int freq, char val, HTreeNode l, HTreeNode r, HTreeNode n, String code) // code is the path taken to this node, how to explain it in code?
    {
        value = val;
        frequency = freq;
        left = l;
        right = r;
        next = n;
        code = ""; // just initialized ,but have to think through logic.
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me correct this, there is only 1 error type, where the input "Node" is required but input "List.Node" is found. I'm now quite sure this is because they are both in the same file, and can probably adjust my code so I require List.Node (because I'm not sure how to get rid of the underlying problem)

Comment: Strange, changing my expected inputs to HLinkedList.HTreeNode didn't work, now getting error where input type "List.Node" is required (and I thought I made the input of such type) but "Node" type is found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend then you should extend `java.util.AbstractSequentialList<E>`, the generic version instead of the raw one.

Your compiler was complaining because either you didn't import the class, or your methods were not public, or you are not invoking them the right way (may you made them non-static and tried to invoke on the class itself).

**Update**

---

I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve, but believe is something that doesn't generate any compiler error (with some comments) -

```
//E is a type parameter, meaning HLinkedList<E> is generic
public class HLinkedList<E> extends java.util.AbstractSequentialList<E> {

    //I think you can keep this private here, this only helps you to implement your
    //version of AbstractSequentialList, for anyone who will be using HLinkedList
    //are not going to worry about it
    private static class HTreeNode {
        public HTreeNode left;
        public HTreeNode right;
        public HTreeNode next;
        public int frequency;
        public char value;
        public String code;

        public HTreeNode(int freq, char val, HTreeNode l, HTreeNode r, HTreeNode n, String code)  {
            value = val;
            frequency = freq;
            left = l;
            right = r;
            next = n;
            code = ""; 
        }
    }

    private HTreeNode head;
    private int nItem; //made this non-static, each instance will need it's own copy

    public HLinkedList()  {
        this.head = null;
        this.nItem = 0;
    }

    public void insertIntoPosition(E element, int position)  {
        // probably create a new node here for element
        // and fix it at the location specified
    }

    //This is an abstract method declared in AbstractSequentialList
    //You need provide an implementation of it
    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {

        return null;
    }

    //This is an abstract method declared in AbstractSequentialList
    //You need provide an implementation of it    
    @Override
    public int size() {

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now imagine, the following is how the clients will be using `HLinkedList` -

```
HLinkedList<Integer> list = new HLinkedList<Integer>();
//or
HLinkedList<String> list = new HLinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: the thing is, I have a bunch of parameters in my self-made nodes (like frequency and code values) that all go red if I extend that and don't have my node declarations in the same file

Comment: that is, if I don't extend, I'm fine with having my Nodetype declared in a separate class and separate file, but once I extend that thing, I have to bring my Nodetype declaration over to the same file, which is screwing my stuff up in other parts of the project

Comment: You should post the relevant code here, so that we know what you are doing.

Comment: edited post. Not sure why extending this would create problems on the node level, unless the extended thing is explicitly defined down to the node level?

Comment: @Sukwoo: You should not accept the answer unless it solves your problem. You should undo it, to let other people come check out your question.

Comment: @Sukwoo: Whatever you are trying to achieve looks really complicated, specially regarding your knowledge of Java. Please, check out the update. Hope you can start from. Now, I think it should be fair enough for you to accept the answer. You can start with that and if any problem comes come back and ask a new question. :)